# RxJS race halts without completion of either stream

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Having the following snippet of code:

```
import { interval, race, Subject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

const a$ = new Subject<number>();
const b$ = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(1));
race([a$, b$]).subscribe(console.log);
a$.subscribe({complete: () => console.log('a$ completed!')});

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(i => a$.next(i));
```

The output in the console is 1...7.
My expectation for the output in the console was, having both observables a$ and b$ not completing, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...

Somehow after all values from the array have been emitted through a$, the values emitted from b$ don't pass. Why is this the case? Does the race operator know a$ is not going to emit anymore? And if so, how does the race operator know this?

Answer (score 1):

*Somehow after all values from the array have been emitted through a$, the values emitted from b$ don't pass. Why is this the case?*

The simple answer is found in the documentation of the [`race` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race).

> The observable to emit first is used.

Since the `map` function of your array will run instantaneously, before `b$` has emitted anything, `a$` will always "win" the race and thus log to the console. `b$` will never "win" nor complete.